pyspark - avoid schema change on unionByName
I want to union two dataframes with similar but different datatypes for one column but keep the original schema.
For example
old_schema_test = StructType(
        [
            StructField("numberField", LongType(), True)
        ]
)

new_schema_test = StructType(
        [
            StructField("numberField", IntegerType(), True)
        ]
)

old_df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(numberField=1)], schema=old_schema_test)
new_df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(numberField=2)], schema=new_schema_test)

union_df = new_df.unionByName(old_df)
union_df.printSchema()


Output:
root
|-- numberField: long (nullable = true)

will output an dataframe where numberField has LongType as this is the 'bigger' datatype.
While this is a valid option as it will always work, I'm looking for an option to preserve the original datatype (i.e. IntegerType) for the column while still joining the dataframes.
My usecase is unifying delta tables where no explicit schema was given. Therefore the schema was infered as similar datatype of different sizes (IntegerType -> LongType, decimal -> double, ...). Now a schema should be applied and overwrite the existing schema of the deltatable.

so, you want a column to have 2 data types at the same time?

A delta table always has a schema! My proposal is always cast your data directly after loading to a desired schema and then make your transformations steps. Overwriting the schema automatically is not always the best way to deal with those problems as data corruptness may occur. Therefore set your schema, make your transformation and save it. Also you can ensure the schema correctness by adding a schema_validation step before writing.

@samkart I want all data to have the same data type. Currently it's different, because the schema got infered.

@SamuelDemir That is exactly what I want to do for future data but to have it uniform I want to transform the historical data to have the same schema. In the end every table should have the same schema. Currently because of an infered schema its different for each table.

@user3657850 Are you using Azure databricks?

Just define the schema you want to have and read in your historical data by sth similar to 'spark.read.schema(source_schema).parquet(path)'. If you want to read it in without a schema 'spark.read.parquet(path)' and cast the fields of the DataFrame by a for loop to your desired schema.

@DileeprajnarayanThumula yes

@SamuelDemir since historical data is already in delta, reading with a given schema will not work.
